# How to make an Android Layout with a bottom button bar and a main area that fills the rest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to make a layout with a main area and a bottom button bar.  Unfortunately, the main area always overlaps the bottom bar.  What am I doing wrong?

The simple code below just contains the main area and the bottom bar, but I can see in the designer that the main area goes to the bottom of the window, despite the constraint

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout__bottomButtons"
```

This is presumably because I also have to put in the following line:

```
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Android complains if you don't have this, so I am wondering how the constraints are supposed to work in this case?

Note: I have tried using "wrap_content" instead but in my real view the content is in a ScrollView, and the ScrollView overlaps the buttons unless I hack around with margins.  I have to think I am missing aomething?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout__main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout__main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout__bottomButtons"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="@+id/layout__main"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout__main"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/layout__main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout__main"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout__main"
            android:id="@+id/layout__bottomButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn__reset_all_options"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:text="Reset"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout__main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout__bottomButtons"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="@+id/layout__main"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout__main"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/layout__main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"//match constraints is appropriate here
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        >
```

you used match parent on the layout__main. Now since the parent is the constraint layout it is going to cover the whole screen. Match constraints( denoted by 0dp) will solve your problem. Match constraints translates as cover as much screen that is available to me defined by the constraints i have

Comment: Using 0dp was looking promising in design view, but when I run the app the main section disappears completely.  I just get the bottom bar.  I am using this layout for an alert dialog (not a normal page), so I guess it is something to do with that.  It seems that the height of the alert dialog is set dynamically but has a maximum so it doesn't use the whole screen. I can't figure out how to define it so the main area uses the maximum space available.  I need this to show a ScrollView in the main area. Any ideas?